# Frequency of RAM

Tags: memory, bios

I have a very old system HP compaq dx2080. It has 1GB of RAM. I recently bought a EVM DDR2 1 GB PC RAM which had a clock rate of 667 MHz. I am dual booting windows 7 and 8.

When I installed it, windows 7 was still using the older 1GB. It showed as 2 GB available and 1 GB usable in system properties. I searched around and found that I can change it to max in the msconfig. I did so. I set it 2048. Still, it was using only 1 GB. When, I switched to 8, it was using the 2gb.

Now, for my question: My system only supported 553MHz and 667MHz RAM. In the BIOS, I saw that the new RAM was showing as up to 800MHz. Rechecked using speccy and CPU-z. It showed different values between the two. The RAM is labeled as 667MHz over it. No mistake in that. But, am I missing something? Please help. And, can I continue using it?

My point again. There are only two slots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try resetting both sticks firmly, then post CPU-Z screenshots for each.

Answer (score 1):

I once had this issue with two 4GB sticks on an older board. Make sure that your RAM cards are positioned in the right DIMMs. Depending on how the board handles dual channel it might have some color coding system with the DIMMs that require you to install kits in matching DIMMs (i.e. both in blue slots or both in black slots. Could be alternating slots or right next to each other). As I mentioned before I had this issue and windows would detect 8GB but only 4GB were usable. This also accompanied BSODs when windows would attempt to reach into my upper 4GB.

This doesn't account for the behavior of windows 8. If my hunch is correct than it could just be that win8 is compensating for this automatically or may be passing a blind eye to the fact.

My advise would be if you have the manual for the board find where it indicates how to install RAM, if not then try reseating the RAM in different slot configurations.

Comment: There are only two slots. They are both of the same color.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the problem, but is your windows 7 and 8 running in 32bit?

My guess is Windows 8 is running 64bit and 7 is running 32bit and that may be your problem in why you cant use it all in windows 7.

Comment: No. Both the versions are 32-bit.

Comment: 2GB should be the max (but working) on a 32bit OS. Where 'max' is defined as 'max sanely usable' and not 'the max you really want to use'.  (For 32 bit address space please do not use more than 512MiB).